# Binary I/O, Finding a specific byte to modify in a file

Tags: c

```
int main()
{

 long int length = 0; /*file byte length*/
 int index;
 FILE *myFile;

     myFile = fopen("test file", "r+b");

 if(!myFile)
 {
   printf("Error, unable to open file");
   return 1;
 }
 else
 {
   /*Lets find the total bytes in the file*/
   fseek(myFile, 0, SEEK_END); /*Seeks end for length*/
   length = ftell(myFile);
   fseek(myFile,0, SEEK_SET); /*seeks beginning for reset*/
   printf("Total file bytes is %d\n",length);
   unsigned char buffer[32]; /*reading into buffer 4 bytes, 32 bits*/
   size_t bytes_read = 0;

   for(index = 0; index < 30; index++) /*30 is just a testing value*/
    {
     bytes_read = fread(&buffer,4,1,myFile); /*Read 4 bytes at a time*/

    printf("Bytes read: %i", bytes_read);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
   }

}




  fclose(myFile);
   return 0;
}
```

Before I continue, yes this is not a efficient program and will create a lot of overhead...

I'm reading in 4 bytes at a time from a file but, do not understand how to read in the actual binary 0's and 1's or hex values in order to compare and modify a hex or binary value. How would I go about reading in the hex/binary values of a program that is opened up here?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying.  Technically, the only thing that you can read in are the 1s and 0s.  Whether it's hex, decimal, or octal is essentially just a representation of what you've read in.  So, as an example, I can do a comparison of 255 == 0xFF.  The underlying  1s and 0s are the same

Comment: ... and just a friendly FYI, your comment on your declaration of "buffer" is incorrect.  You actually are declaring 32 bytes, not 32 bits

Comment: @Don Shankin, I imagined I was taking individual bits of each byte giving me the 32 bits, but now I know

Comment: @Don Shankin, also my program is not giving me binary values but random ascii values

Comment: ASCII values are just binary values interpreted as characters. Look on an ASCII table to see which hex values each ASCII character represents, or just reconfigure your print statements to print in hex directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see the values in your binary files *printed* as hex bytes, try the following:

Change your declaration of buffer to:

```
uint32_t buffer;
```

and your printf to:

```
printf("0x%0X\n", buffer);
```

using the `uint32_t` type will keep your fread in line with your buffer on machines on which ints may not be 32 bits.  To use it, you may need to

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

Using your fread, this will read 4 bytes from your file into a 4 byte type.  This will then be printed as a hex value.

Answer (score 0):

Your buffer is 32 bytes large; the array parameter sets the size in terms of the unit. On most systems, an unsigned char is 1 byte (8 bits), so your buffer is 8*32 bits in size.

As it stands, you buffer contains 4 bytes of file and then 28 empty bytes after.

You can operate on those first 4 bytes like you would any value in an array, ex

```
if (0x2 == buffer[0])
{
    printf("I found a 2 in hex!");
}
```